# Reinstalling Wubi Ubuntu with old root.disk file

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, wubi

I recently successfully recovered Windows 7 with a Disk. However, this recovery has taken out my boot option for Ubuntu, which I downloaded through Wubi (Wubi installs Ubuntu as a folder within Windows 7).

Now, Windows DID preserve the Ubuntu folder, it just took out the boot option. So I DO have the root.disk file, and I have successfully copied it and backed it up on Windows as well as on an external storage device. I know that I probably have to reinstall Wubi/Ubuntu in order to make it functional again.

My question is, will I simply be able to replace the old root.disk with the new root.disk? I really, really need the files on the old Ubuntu install, so if there's anything I can do to get them back conveniently, please let me know.

Comment: Anything at all? :(

Comment: Patience is a virtue.

Answer (score 0):

That should work, yes. `root.disk` is nothing more than a raw image of an ext4 filesystem, so if all you need is the files, you can also easily access them from an Ubuntu live CD (or, likely, from any other distro's live CD) – just mount it as a loop device, using `mount -o loop /blah/root.disk /mnt`.